# Mapping route to directory structure on file system in Silex

Tags: routes, server, silex

I have this directory hierarchy:

```
htdocs
  |-- project
    |-- public
      |-- module
        |-- feature
          |-- index.php
```

On a sample **GET** request like

```
http://example.com/module/feature/1/email@server.com
```

how the server (Apache) knows that my directory is `feature` and not `1` or `email@server.com`?

Do I need to do any further configuration somewhere or does the Apache server do the magic for me out of the box?

Do I need to configure any routes on Silex too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How the server (Apache) knows that my directory is `feature` and not `1` or `email@server.com`?

Silex has a [Routing System](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.0/usage.html#routing). You pass a route to the request method (`get` here) and that way the request is captured.

## Getting all the features:

```
// htdocs/project/public/modules/features/index.php
$app->get('/modules/features', function (Application $app, Request $request) {

    $features = $app['em']->getRepository(Feature::class)->findAll();

    return $app['twig']->render('features/index.html.twig', array(
        'items' => $features,
    ));

});
```

## Getting the feature number #1:

```
// htdocs/project/public/modules/features/index.php
$app->get('/modules/features/{id}', function (Application $app, Request $request) {

    $id = $request->get('id');
    $feature = $app['em']->getRepository(Feature::class)->find($id);

    return $app['twig']->render('features/show.html.twig', array(
        'items' => $feature,
    ));

});
```

So, that is **YOU**, not **Apache** that decide what to return on which request.

> Do I need to do any further configuration somewhere or does the Apache server do the magic for me out of the box?
>
> Do I need to configure any routes on Silex too?

Yes! You should and could define your routes. Note the `'/modules/features'` & `'/modules/features/{id}'` parts in snippets above.

## URL Path vs Filesystem Directories

[URLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) have a hierarchical categorising system called Path, and [File System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) has a similar thing too, despite of the fact that they are totally separate things.

They are not intended to be the same all the time, although they could be as a rule of simplicity.

Thus, you may map this URL:

```
http://example.com/modules/features
```

to both of these File System locations:

```
htdocs/project/public/modules/features/index.php
```

&

```
htdocs/project/public/Controller/Frontend/modules/features/index.php
```

## Final Note

You would better take advantage of **Directory Structure Best Practices**. examples are:

- [Silex: getting your project structure right](https://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/01/silex-getting-your-project-structure-right/)
- [aptoma/silex-bootstrap](https://github.com/aptoma/silex-bootstrap)
- [silex file structure for custom service providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239962/silex-file-structure-for-custom-service-providers)

& [PHP Namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)